# Get-NetAdapter Powershell does not list all adapters

Tags: powershell, networking, adapter

I want to list all network adapters:
[image]

I use the cmdlet **Get-NetAdapter** as I also want to list the LinkSpeed of the adapters.
But Get-NetAdapters shows all adapters except of the **_SSLVPN_NA_VA_FullTrusted_Access-mas** adapter. It is a VPN connection via F5.

**How can I also include this adapter ?**

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `Get-VPNConnection`?

Comment: Does `Get-NetAdapter -Name * -IncludeHidden` not include "_SSLVPN_NA_VA_FullTrusted_Access-mas"?